# Sending message from Flask to JS via socketio

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to wrap my head around this socketio thing and have hit a wall regarding sending a message from my Flask backend to my JavaScript frontend. My app is a consolidated control panel for my church's PTZ camera and OBS Studio. Here are the logical steps I'm trying to implement:

1. Connect Flask to OBS via the OBS websocket.
2. Receive notification in Flask when the Graphics source visibility in OBS changes.
3. Send a message from Flask to my JS frontend to let it know that the Graphics source has changed visibility (making a two-way sync with the button on my control panel and the actual source in OBS).

Steps 1 and 2 are working, but I can't get the 3rd one to work.

Here is my Python where I use the message from OBS to call the function to sync with the JS frontend. (I know the sync_graphics_toggle runs, but the JS never gets the emit message.)

```
def on_visibility_change(message):
    if (message.getItemName() == "Graphics"):
        sync_graphics_toggle(message.getItemVisible())

def sync_graphics_toggle(obs_graphics_visible):
    socketio.emit('syncGraphicsToggle', obs_graphics_visible, namespace='/main')
```

In the JavaScript (with just a console log to test):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const socketMain = io("/main");
  socketMain.on("connect", function() {
    console.log("Made connection in graphics-preview", socketMain.id);
  });
  socketMain.on("syncGraphicsToggle", function(obsGraphicsVisible) {
    console.log("Got syncGraphicsToggle command")
  });
}
```

I have verified that I'm connected, but I don't get the message from Flask.

I have other implementations of socketio in my code that work fine, but those are initiated by actions on the webpage. So, I'm thinking there is something I don't understand about sending messages that are initiated by the server.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

John

- Windows 10
- Python = 3.10.4
- Flask = 2.2.2
- Python Socket.IO = 5.7.2
- JS Socket.IO = 4.5.3